# htaccess - redirect non-www - but exclude specific subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a system where multiple domains share one htaccess. At the Moment I redirect all non-www-requests to www using the following.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
Only Problem is now I can't use Subdomains at all because sub-domain.myhost.com will be redirected to www.sub-domain.myhost.com.
Is there a way where the Above rule could e.g. exclude all requests starting with 'sub-'? And NOT redirect those to www.

UPDATE:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!(?:sub-|www)\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Having only the  above 5 Lines in my .htaccess will throw a "500 - Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple tweak:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!(?:sub-|www)) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The negative lookahead `(?!(?:sub-|www))` asserts thatwhat follows is not `sub-` or `www`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I only change this two lines I'm getting a 500 - Internal Server Error. If you're sure it should work I will check the rest of my htaccess if it interferes somehow.

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing else interfering.

Comment: Sorry Tom, when I edited the first line I introduced a typo. Now fixed, please try again.

Comment: @zx81 Still "Internal Server Error" with only the 5 Lines. (Just seen you're update -> will try)